# PHP Logger VPN / Proxy detection via file_get_contents and preg_match

Tags: php

I tried to add VPN / Proxy detection in my PHP Logger but I don't know exactly how to do it. I'm trying to get the info VPN and Proxy `True` or `False` from [https://ip.teoh.io/{$ipaddress}](https://ip.teoh.io/%7B$ipaddress%7D) with preg_match but it didn't work.

Code:

```
    else{
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ipaddress}"));//replace 172.217.21.238 with {$ipaddress}
    $country = $details->country;
    $region = $details->region;
    $city = $details->city;
    $content = file_get_contents("https://ip.teoh.io/{$ipaddress}");
    preg_match("/\<td colspan\=\"2\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>/""#</tr><tr><td>VPN</td><td>(.*?)</td></tr><tr>#", $content, $m); echo $m[1];
    preg_match("~</tr><tr><td>Proxy</td><td>(.+?)</td></tr><tr>~", $content, $m); echo $m[1];
  }
  
 file_put_contents('.\txt\visitor infos.txt',"Date : ". date("Y-m-d - H:i:s"). " | IP: ". $ipaddress. " | Country: ". $country. " | Region: ". $region. " | City: ". $city. " | OS: ". $user_os. " | Browser: ". $user_browser. " | Come from site: ". $site. " | User-Agent: " .$user_agent .PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Teoh.io has an API: https://ip.teoh.io/vpn-proxy-api ... use that instead to get a JSON response. Ipinfo.io also has an API, but it seems you need to sign up. https://ipinfo.io/ip-geolocation-api ... bottom line, please review what you're trying to do, if you're using `json_encode`, ensure you're actually calling a proper API URL with a JSON response.

Comment: Example: https://ip.teoh.io/api/vpn/172.217.21.238

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAO worked

Comment: Glad to hear, and thanks for posting your outcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tanks for the help MarkusAO the whole code:

```
<?php

// Getting IP
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']."";
    }
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."";
    }
else
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."";
    }
// END of Getting IP
//
// Getting User-Agent
$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// END of Getting User-Agent
//
// Getting OS Name
function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array       =   array(
                            '/windows nt 10/i'      =>  'Windows 10',
                            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                            '/cros/i'               =>  'Chrome OS',
                            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                                          '/kalilinux/i'          =>  'KaliLinux',
                            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile',
                                          '/Windows Phone/i'      =>  'Windows Phone'
                            );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $os_platform    =   $value;
        }

    }   

    return $os_platform;

}
// END of Getting OS Name
//
// Getting Browser
function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

    $browser_array  =   array(
                            '/msie/i'                     =>  'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'                  =>  'Firefox',
                            '/Mozilla/i'                    =>  'Mozila',
                            '/Mozilla\/5\.0/i'              =>  'Mozila',
                            '/safari/i'                   =>  'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'                   =>  'Chrome',
                            '/edge/i'                     =>  'Edge',
                            '/opera/i'                    =>  'Opera',
                                          '/OPR/i'                      =>  'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'                 =>  'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'                  =>  'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i'                =>  'Konqueror',
                                          '/Bot/i'                        =>    'BOT Browser',
                                          '/Valve Steam GameOverlay/i'  =>  'Steam',
                            '/mobile/i'                   =>  'Handheld Browser'
                        );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $browser    =   $value;
        }

    }

    return $browser;

}
// END Getting Browser
//
//Setting Os and Browser Variables
$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();
//
// Getting where visitor comes from (URL)
$site_refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    // Check if hes connected directly 
    if($site_refer == ""){
        $site = "dirrect connection";
    }
  // If he isn't
    else{
        $site = $site_refer;
    }
  // Hide Owner's IP address
    $owner = "::1";   //Change $owner for something else, cuz someone can simple read that by calling out $owner
  // change it for $absdfs5sd4 for example and change it down there 
    $owner_country = "Not avaible";
  
    if($ipaddress == $owner){
        $ipaddress = "Not avaible"; 
    $country = $owner_country;
    $region = $owner_country;
    $city = $owner_country;
    }
  //Find info about IP address
    else{
        $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/172.217.21.238"));//replace 172.217.21.238 with {$ipaddress}
    $country = $details->country;
    $region = $details->region;
    $city = $details->city;
    $detail = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ip.teoh.io/api/vpn/172.217.21.238"));//replace 172.217.21.238 with {$ipaddress}
    $organization = $detail->organization;
    $vpn_or_proxy = $detail->vpn_or_proxy;
  }
  
    // Writing in to txt file
 file_put_contents('.\txt\visitor infos.txt',"Date : ". date("Y-m-d - H:i:s"). " | IP: ". $ipaddress. " | ISP: ". $organization. " | Country: ". $country. " | Region: ". $region. " | City: ". $city. " | VPN: ". $vpn_or_proxy. " | OS: ". $user_os. " | Browser: ". $user_browser. " | Come from site: ". $site. " | User-Agent: " .$user_agent .PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 echo "Date : ". date("Y-m-d - H:i:s"). " | IP: ". $ipaddress. " | ISP: ". $organization. " | Country: ". $country. " | Region: ". $region. " | City: ". $city. " | VPN: ". $vpn_or_proxy. " | OS: ". $user_os. " | Browser: ". $user_browser. " | Come from site: ". $site. " | User-Agent: " .$user_agent;
 file_put_contents('.\txt\ips clean.txt', $ipaddress. "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```